# How to convert Data retrieved from an ftp URL in to usable objects in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ftp, nsdata

I'm trying to parse a range of different files retrieved from an ftp directory: ftp://ftp.bom.gov.au/anon/gen/radar/

The file types include: .png , .gif , .shtml , .html and .json.

I've got the raw `Data` with:

```
let url = URL(string: "ftp://ftp.bom.gov.au/anon/gen/radar/")
    var data: Data? = nil
    if let anUrl = url {
        do {
            try data = Data(contentsOf: anUrl)

        }
        catch {
        }
    }
```

but I can't work out how to parse the data into individual objects.

I can see they are there by using:

```
if let actualData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) {
                print(actualData)
            }
```

which prints to the console:

```
-rw-rw-r--    1 1050     1502         5842 Apr 05 00:14 IDR784.T.201904050012.png

-rw-rw-r--    1 1050     1502         5774 Apr 05 00:20 IDR784.T.201904050018.png

-rw-rw-r--    1 1050     1502        19176 Apr 05 00:20 IDR784.gif

-rw-rw-r--    1 1050     1502        17796 Apr 04 23:01 IDR78I.T.201904042301.png
```

for the 5000+ files (approximately 30mb) the `Data` contains.

I've searched everywhere I can think of including Apples CFNetwork Programming Guide - Working with FTP Servers but can't make heads or tails of that.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are not getting any file data. You are only getting a directory listing. You need to access a specific file to get that file's data.

Comment: FYI - do not use `Data(contentsOf:)` to access remote data. Use `URLSession`.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, you should be using URLSession to download data instead of Data(contentsOf:).  If you continue down your current path, you'll probably want to set up an NSRegularExpression to parse the data.  First split the large string into an array of strings using `.components(separatedBy: .newlines)`.  Then use the regular expression to match the file names you're looking for.

Instead of just making raw requests, you might find it easier using a FTP library.  A quick search landed at this potential option:

https://github.com/Constantine-Fry/rebekka